# Jedis Subscribe thread get Connection time out exception every fixed interval

Tags: java, sockets, redis, publish-subscribe, jedis

In my application i have 4 redis channel , the application subscribes to this channel in 4 different thread , but in long run for every 4 hours i get the exception in all 4 threads which had subscribed to those channels.

> java.net.SocketException: Connection time out (Read failed)

i am not able to find the exact reason for this timeout , if any input from you all will be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to return the jedis connection to JedisPool?

Comment: the channel is ideal for long time , as subscribe call is blocking call the connection will be kept within the thread , and all the threads which are listening on 4 different channels are getting this exception.

Comment: Did you set timeout to Redis configuration?

Comment: yes i had set 2000 has the connectiontimeout and sotimeout.

Comment: but according to jedis code, jedis set timeout to infinite in subscribe method.

Comment: You had to set 0 in the configuration, see the following notes and example available in the configuration file –

`# Close the connection after a client is idle for N seconds (0 to disable)`

`timeout 0`